# JSSOR Slider - Call images from album hosted online, possibly through RSS Feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, slider, jssor

First, the reason I am looking to do this is that loading images into the slider is really bogging down my site's performance.

I'm wondering if there is a way to pull in images from an album that is hosted externally, specifically through Google Picasa albums (I'm open to other platforms if they are better suited for it). I would just use their slideshow embed code but it's pretty horrendous.

Could this be done by calling an RSS feed within JSSOR Slider?

Would it even improve site performance or would I have the same issues pulling images from elsewhere?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if what I'm asking isn't best practice or if it doesn't make sense to approach it this way, I'm just trying to improve functionality/performance on my personal portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try lazy loading? If not, please try specify `src2` attribute instead of `src` to define a lazy loading image.

```
<div><img u="image" src2="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added lazy loading and it definitely improved site speed, but it's still having trouble loading on mobile. Sometimes it does, sometimes it gets stuck in a refresh cycle.

Do you have any other tricks that might work? I realize that loading 50 total jpgs into multiple sliders was probably not the intention of the code so if I'm over-tasking the page I can just slim it down.